# Cant set state using UseEffect in React.FC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a react functional component that is making an API call. it is for sure getting a response when it makes the call. I am trying to save the array into a state so that it can be retrieved and used with other sub components. when i console log inside the response before it is saved i get:

`console.log(response.data)` I get `[{},{}]`

and my code is

```
const [helpFiles, setHelpFiles] = useState<HelpDTO[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        helpApi.getHelpFiles().then((response) => {
            if (response.status !== 200) return;
            console.log(response.data)
            setHelpFiles(response.data.data);
        });
    })
```

`response.data.data` is undefined, but if I try to save `response.data` it throws an error:

```
Argument of type 'HelpGetResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<HelpDTO[]>'.
  Type 'HelpGetResponse' is not assignable to type '(prevState: HelpDTO[]) => HelpDTO[]'.
    Type 'HelpGetResponse' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: HelpDTO[]): HelpDTO[]'.
```

so i have to save it as `response.data.data`

but then it comes up as undefined when it is saving...

I have no idea how to save the response properly...

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing state like this with an empty array.

```
const [helpFiles, setHelpFiles] = useState([]);
```

Console log only the response and check the console. Find which part of the response is holding the array you need.